I have two button and there are multiple views at the top of those two buttons. adjusting zPosition = 1000 they are visible but not clickable
I have two button and there are multiple views at the top of those two buttons. So after using vwButtons.layer.zPosition = 1000 they are visible but not clickable
i tried using vwButtons.layer.zPosition = 1000 and also self.view.bringSubviewToFront(vwButtons) but still not working they are visible but click event is not fired. Please check image attacheddetails image

zPosition will change the postion of layer and click event is bind to while view hence it cannot capture it. Try to add button at last so it always remains on top

@JayGajjar so is there any solution to it?

is any superview of your buttons is image view?
please check view.subviews.forEach { print($0.isUserInteractionEnabled) }

@Immanuel superview to buttons is uiview

@HarshParekh, please share minimum code for reproducing issue

There are different viewcontroller files as i'm using stickyHeader for scrolling screens. vwButton are inside MainVC and then ContainerViewVC and then HeaderVC and BottomVC for single scrolling.. As all of them are used for pageviewcontroller feature and my bottomVC will have collection view and table view so it's necessary to use stickyheader for single scrolling

@HarshParekh - difficult to tell from the image you posted, but... Are you referring to the "Follow / Support" buttons? Do you have UI elements that are covering the buttons?

You can run the app in simulator and while its running press the "Debug view hierarchy" button in Xcode.

It will show you if your buttons are being overlapped by some other transparent views.
Also you could use this method
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(vwButtons)


please check the attached image

@HarshParekh, Follow & Support button is not clickable? If yes, I can see those buttons are in a view which is behind another view so the touches are not being passed to them. You need to bring their superview to front as well.
